# css-formatted tabular divs ['table'] w/fixed header and both x/y scrolling

Tags: css, scroll

I've found a number of posts on stackoverflow that address similar problems to mine, but none of them are similar enough, and I just can't solve this... I have tabular output that may exceed a viewing area in width, height, or both. The output is accompanied by a header. If the output exceeds the height, the user should be able to scroll up/down, but **the header must remain fixed**. If the output exceeds the horizontal area, the user should be able to scroll left/right, and **the header must move w/the content**.

I've tried various combinations of overflow:scroll, overflow:scroll-x [and scroll-y], overflow:auto, w/the table header both part of the content, and separate from it. I've met w/only mixed success ; either I can get the header to scroll l/r along w/the content and it disappears on vertical scrolling, or I can get the header to remain fixed in case of vertical scrolling, but it remains fixed if the output is scrolled horizontally.

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnH4G) w/some html that I used as a starting point.

```
[code]jsfiddle code[/code]
```

## Constraints

- the output must be divs, as in the example. I can't use <table>
- the solution must be css/html only, no j/s, jquery, etc.

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve that with pure css/html even if you give an element `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;`. by doing that you can't move the element because while scrolling element's position on the page does not change and it is impossible to get element's scroll value from css or html.

So the only solution you can find is in using javascript

Answer (score 1):

If you can set a width to some of your divs this can be a starting point using pure css/html:

```
.row div, .head div {
    display: inline;
}
.head, .rows {
    width: 160px;
}
.rows {
    height: 40px;            // this height is set to force scroll
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.tbl {
    width: 100px;            // this width is set to mimic small width
    overflow: auto;
}


<div class='tbl'>
    <div class='head'>
        <div>head 1</div>  <div>head 2</div>  <div>head 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class='rows'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div>data 1</div>  <div>data 1</div>  <div>data 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div>data 2</div>  <div>data 2</div>  <div>data 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div>data 2</div>  <div>data 2</div>  <div>data 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jL4ch/

Comment: wonderful! but i still have a small problem. when i make the table larger, `inline` causes the data to run together even using `min-width` (see [link](http://i1222.photobucket.com/albums/dd496/frabjousday123/Untitled-1.jpg)). it looks better when i use `display:table-cell`, but then the header cells start to 'wander' the farther out the columns go (see [link](http://i1222.photobucket.com/albums/dd496/frabjousday123/Untitled-2.jpg)). the same when i nest (using `table-header-group`, etc.) and using `min-width` gives me 2 scrollbars. :/ any ideas how i can get rid of the header column wandering?

Comment: Changing `inline` to `inline-block` to force setting `min-width` and you might need to set `white-space: nowrap;` to keep text at 1 line ... Check all margins/paddings to see if those cause the "wander" (or update your code at jsfiddle so I can look) ... also check so your header cells are within same `table` as the rows

Comment: thank you. i'd vote you up, but i haven't been around long enough. :/

Answer (score 0):

i figured this out. there are several things to take note of :

- the widths can be made to function w/any inline block-structuring style, including `inline-block`, for example. you don't have to use `table-cell`. using only `inline` will cause the browser to disregard the `width:` elements.
- it's pretty silly, but if you use `overflow-x`, you also have to state an `overflow-y` policy *explicitly*, or you get 2 scrollbars. the trick was to declare the axis w/the desired constraint as `auto` and the other overflow as `hidden`.

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/n34eW) is a jsfiddle that illustrates my solution. the fiddle has inlined widths because in real life, the tabular data will actually be generated dynamically and the column widths won't ever have the same values, as they do here in the example.